# using Tikz with lyx

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, installing

I have to following code in the ERT-

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and of cousre I have `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble.
Using TexWorks I can compile the file properly, but on lyx (exporting with pdflatex, same as in texworks) I get an empty page.  According to the MikTex package manager the pgf version is 3.

what is the problem here? do I have to install `tikz` seperatley?

the `.lyx` file:

```
    % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[10pt,english,hebrew]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[samesize]{cancel}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be best to provide a complete minimal example either the `.lyx` file or the equivalent `.tex`. (More people can help with the latter.)

Comment: @cfr is it ok now?

Comment: Thanks. I don't seem to have the font I'd need to compile your example, but somebody else probably will. In the `.lyx` file, why do you change to `cp1255` before the `tikzpicture`? Do you know how this is supported? I'm guessing you've installed additional stuff to support Hebrew and that probably provides that encoding, is that right?

Comment: it's becaue I added text too, but the change to `cp1255` was done aotumatically

Comment: @cfr i removed it from the file

Comment: Do you have the required fonts installed? That is, you don't get complaints about missing fonts?

Comment: Try putting `\inputencoding{latin9}\selectlanguage{english}` before the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @cfr it worked. and also puting `%\inputencoding{cp1255}
%\selectlanguage{hebrew}` after the code to continue writing in Hebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this because I don't have the required fonts installed. However, the OP has confirmed that it works.

Adding

```
\inputencoding{latin9}\selectlanguage{english}
```

before the `tikzpicture` is probably needed as PGF/Ti*k*Z probably cannot cope with Hebrew, right-to-left typesetting and `cp1255`.

To switch back to Hebrew, you can use

```
\inputencoding{cp1255}\selectlanguage{hebrew}
```

Alternatively, you can apply the switch locally within a group. For example,

```
{%
  \inputencoding{latin9}\selectlanguage{english}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) --(1,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

should do it